# Problema al integrar AdminLTE - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of undefined

Tags: angular, web, adminlte

estoy desarrollando un proyecto en angular con AdminLTE 3. Resulta que ya lo instalé, puse los estilos, scripts y fuentes. Pero me sale un error en consola con el siguiente mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A alguien le ha pasado algo similar? Ya he trabajado con AdminLTE 3 con java web y no tuve este problema. También probé instalando el adminLTE con npm pero tampoco funciona u.u

Comment: Usarlo en Angular es un poco complicado por el tema de tener que cargar javascript externo. Es mejor que uses una plantilla hecha en Angular como ngx-admin

Comment: Hola @Lobos, muchas gracias por su respuesta. Efectivamente estoy teniendo muchos problemas con eso. Voy a buscar acerca de ngx-admin. Saludos